# DHCPd IP dispatch

Tags: centos, dhcp-server, dhcpd

For my tests, the following was done with 2 virtual machines. The server is under CentOS7 and the client under Windows 10 (MAC : 08:00:27:bd:3d:ab).

After every modification on the server side, I perform a release/renew on the client to check if it get the IP I want.

Here is the configuration :

```
authoritative;
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 28800;
max-lease-time 36000;
allow bootp;

next-server 192.168.0.254;
filename "pxelinux.0";

shared-network {
    subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
        option broadcast-address 192.168.0.127;
        option routers 192.168.0.1;
        option ntp-servers 192.168.0.1;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;

        class "matchHW" {
            match hardware;
        }

        group {
            deny unknown-clients;
            subclass "matchHW" 1:08:00:27:bd:3d:ab;
        }

        group {
            deny unknown-clients;
            host win10 {
                hardware ethernet f8:00:27:bd:3d:ab;
                fixed-address 192.168.0.13;
            }
        }

        pool {
            allow members of "matchHW";
            option routers 192.168.0.3;
            option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.3;
            range 192.168.0.40 192.168.0.49;
        }

        pool {
            allow unknown-clients;
            option routers 192.168.0.2;
            option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.2;
            range 192.168.0.30 192.168.0.39;
        }
    }
}
```

In this specific configuration, I don't understand why the Windows client get for it's IP 192.168.0.30 with .1 for it's GW. I expect it get 192.168.0.40 with .3 for it's GW.

If I switch the 2 MACs (08:00:27:bd:3d:ab, f8:00:27:bd:3d:ab) to get a static IP, it works (get 192.168.0.13). If I edit these MAC to come with my client with an unknown MAC, it works too (get 192.168.0.30).

The final goal of my configuration is to serve IP for 3 "groups" :

- static IP for known MAC
- dynamic IP for known MAC
- dynamic IP for unknown MAC

Each of these groups will have specific routers and DNS configuration.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, thanks to these two links :

- [Bill Shirley-2, second post](http://isc-dhcp-users.2343191.n4.nabble.com/Problems-using-class-match-by-user-option-td2294.html)
- [Mcwilliams, Rhys, first post](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2008-May/006372.html)

Here is my working configuration :

```
shared-network {

    subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
        option broadcast-address 192.168.0.127;
        option routers 192.168.0.1;
        option ntp-servers 192.168.0.1;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;

        # known clients - dynamic IP
        pool {
            allow known-clients;
            range 192.168.0.40 192.168.0.49;
        }

        # unknown clients - dynamic IP
        pool {
            allow unknown-clients;
            deny known-clients;
            option routers 192.168.0.2;
            option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.2;
            range 192.168.0.30 192.168.0.39;
        }
    }

}

# known clients - dynamic IP
group {
    deny unknown-clients;
    option routers 192.168.0.3;
    option ntp-servers 192.168.0.3;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.3;

    host dyn-A {
        hardware ethernet f8:00:27:bd:3d:ab;
    }
}

# known clients - static IP
group {
    deny unknown-clients;
    option routers 192.168.0.1;
    option ntp-servers 192.168.0.1;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;

    host win10 {
        hardware ethernet e8:00:27:bd:3d:ab;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.13;
    }
}
```